# Arithmetic to the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning Java currently and am asking for help with a portion of a particular lab exercise.

"Write a methods to calculate and return the minimum and a method to calculate and return the maximum value in the array.  Write an additional method that accepts the array as a parameter and then creates and returns a new array with all the same values as the original plus 10."

My question (if it makes sense of course) is how to extend this addition to the rest of the elements in the variable. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Max_Min
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {       
  int[] minimumArray = new int[10];

  insertNumbers(minimumArray);
  System.out.print("Minimum Number is: " + minNumber(minimumArray));
  System.out.print("\nMaximum Number is: " + maxNumber(minimumArray));
  System.out.print("\nOriginal Array plus 10: " + plusTen(minimumArray));
 } 


 public static void insertNumbers(int[] minimumArray)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  minimumArray[i] = input.nextInt();

  input.close();

 }

public static int minNumber(int[] array)
 { 
  int minNumber = array[0];

  for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
     if (minNumber > array[i])
         minNumber = array[i];

    return minNumber;
 }


public static int maxNumber(int[] array)
{ 
  int maxNumber = array[0];

  for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
     if (maxNumber < array[i])
         maxNumber = array[i];

    return maxNumber;
 }

 public static int plusTen(int[] array)
 {
int plusTen = array[0] + 10;


 return plusTen;
 }     
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: Under the code portion 

     
 public static int plusTen(int[] array)

 {


int plusTen = array[0] + 10;


 
return plusTen;
 
}     


array[0] + 10 outputs the element at [0] + 10. I would like to add + 10 to the other elements in the array as well.

Comment: you can add a sample of the result you get, and how does it fit to what you expect?

Comment: Plus 10 values or plus the value 10?

Comment: **Requirement** is important. It clearly says `returns a new array with all the same values as the original plus 10`, not `int`.

Comment: You will need to use `Arrays.toString` in order to print the array at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem statement reads:

> Write an additional method that accepts the array as a parameter and then creates and returns a new array with all the same values as the original plus 10.

This requires you to create a new array with same values as the original, and then add 10 to each element. But your code adds 10 only to the first element of the array.

**You can do something like this:**

```
   public static int[] plusTen(int[] array)
 {
   int plusTenArray = new int[array.length];

   for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        plusTenArray[i] = array[i] + 10;
    }

 return plusTenArray;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to assist me, thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

As per problem statement you need to create a separate array and return it.

```
public static int [] plusTen(int[] array)  
{  
    int[] plusTen = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        plusTen[i] = array[i] + 10;
    return plusTen;  
}
```

The call to `plusTen` method from `main` method should be like this:

```
System.out.print("\nOriginal Array plus 10: " + Arrays.toString(plusTen(minimumArray)));
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to assist me, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct this is what you are looking for:

```
public static int[] plusTen(int[] array) {

    int[] plusTen = new int[array.length];

    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        plusTen[i] = array[i] + 10;
    }

    return plusTen;
}
```

Instead of looping over the array here you were simply creating an int with the value of the first index [0] + 10.

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to assist me, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sitting in front of an IDE right now and I'm writing on a phone, but here's some pseudocode:

```
int[] newArray = new int[array.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = array[i] + 10;
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to assist me, thank you for the help!